# Revert RecordType back to Master (default)

Tags: workflow, record-type, field-update

I have a "single" RecordType on Opportunity called "Opportunity Locked", this RecordType is set automatically when an Opportunity is ClosedWon using a workflow rule. My profiles do not have access to the RecordType, their default is Master.

My issue is I cannot update back to master (null/blank) via Dev Console / Data loader / workbench.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't reckon it was possible to revert back to the Master Record Type once a custom record type was created. This [idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aMX4AAM) seems to confirm that suspicion

Comment: Yep. I think I'm going to have to implement Opportunity Unlocked type and revert them back to that.